# Union of choice functions is a choice function

Tags: functions, axiom-of-choice

I'm working on a problem and one part of my solution works only if a union of choice functions is a choice function. The best idea I have is to use that a choice function can be represented as $$ f = \{(\{a\}, a)\} $$ for any set (I used a Singleton for convenience) and that taking union of such choice functions will result in a well defined function that will be a choice function by definition but that really doesn't look like it works for me. Do I'm asking for any hint and/or help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that a union of functions is not necessarily a function. But indeed, if $\mathcal F=\{f_i\mid i\in I\}$ are all choice functions (from their respective domains) and $\bigcup\cal F$ **is** a function, then it is a choice function.

This is clear since $F(a)=f_i(a)$ for some $i$ such that $a\in\operatorname{dom} f_i$, and $f_i$ *is* a choice function, so $F(a)=f_i(a)\in a$.

---

Of course, in topics related to the axiom of choice, one has another caveat. Suppose that $A$ is a set of non-empty sets, you might be inclined to choose for each $a\in A$ a choice function, $f_a$ which chooses an element from $a$, and then take $\mathcal F=\{f_a\mid a\in A\}$, and appeal to the above.

But in order to prove that $\mathcal F$ even exists you already appealed to the axiom of choice in choosing $f_a$ for each $a\in A$.

Whether or not this is your proof strategy, this is something to keep an eye for.

Comment: But is union of choice functions necessarily a function? Assuming they're choice functions on a set of subsets of a set? Because my proof doesn't work if that's not true.

Comment: As I said the union of *functions* is not necessarily a function. The fact that they are choice functions is irrelevant to this. Set $a=\{0,1\}$, then $f(a)=0$ and $g(a)=1$ are both choice functions, but $f\cup g$ is not even a function. If however you can prove that the union *is* a function, then yes, the union will be a choice function.